# Why does this function that removes the first occurrence of a string from another string not work correctly?

Tags: python, string

I tried to write a function that removes the first occurrence of a string from another string:

```
def removesubstr(substr, x):
    a = len(substr)
    m = ""
    count = 0
    b = 0
    c = len(x)
    while count < c:
        for i in x:
            if x[b:b+a] == substr:
                count = count + 1
                m = m + ""
                b = b + a
            else:
                b = b + 1
                m = m + i
                count = count + 1
        return m

print(removesubstr('ara', 'jayaram'))
```

I'm looking to get an output like `'jaym'`, but I realized that since it's looping 3 steps, Python still takes the full last 3 characters `[4:7]` as valid and outputs `'jayram'`. What do I need to change to get `'jaym'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tempstr='jayaram'
tempstr=tempstr.replace("ara", "",1);
```

You can use python inbuilt replace.you can replace it by blank

Comment: what does the 3rd argument in replace do?

Comment: it is optional argument ,tells python how many times you can replace the matched sub-string. if the 3rd argument is 1 it just replace only the first occurrence of matched string

Comment: this looks way simpler :) thanks. 1 hour down the drain though

Comment: @Kunkka if this answers you question, consider accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are supposed to do this yourself rather than using the built in library functions...

You seem to be making this rather more complicated than you need to, you should also use much more meaningful variable names. `a`, `b`, and `m` are all meaningless.

You want something like:

```
sublen = len(substr)
strlen = len(x)
loop = 0
while loop+sublen < strlen:
    loop = loop +1;
    if x[loop:loop+sublen] == substr:
         return x[0:loop]+x[loop+sublen:strlen]

return x
```

Comment: thank you :) out of curiosity , will this also work if you want to remove the first few characters? considering you're incrementing the count variable right at the start of the loop

Comment: @Kunkka yeah, you probably want to start from 0. Honestly my python is a little rusty but I think strings are 0 indexed. You should really use a for loop for this anyway. In java it would be for (i=0;i<loop+sublen;i++) ... as I said my python is rusty though.

Comment: i tried shifting the loop count to the end of the loop. it works perfectly except if the substring falls in the last (eg : ram in jayaram). then the function returns none. possibly because the index falls out of the range in the x[loop+sublen:strlen] part.

Comment: @Kunkka You might need to do a specific check for that (i.e. if loop+sublen = strlen-1 then just return x[0:loop].

Answer (score -1):

```
def remove(s, text):
  if text.find(s) == -1:
        return text
  else:
    new = text[0:text.find(s)]+text[text.find(s)+len(s):len(text)]
    return new
```