# Removing the first occurrence of a string from another string in Python

Tags: python, string

I am trying to write a function that will remove the first occurrence of a string from another string, like:

```
remove("an", "banana") == "bana"
```

The goal is **not** to use a built-in method, but rather to make up my own function using slicing and indexing techniques.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
def remove(substring, string):
    sublen = len(substring)
    new_string = "" 
  
    for i in range(len(string)): 
        # test if string slices are different from substring and if
        # they are, add them to new_string variable
        if string[i:i+sublen+1] != substring:
            new_string += string[i:i+sublen+1]
    return new_string
```

I have come across another post where someone asked the same question as I did ([Write a function that removes the first occurrence of a string from another string.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823967/write-a-function-that-removes-the-first-occurrence-of-a-string-from-another-stri)), but I could not understand how the solutions offered were supposed to work. I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction, or at least help understand what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Refactoring your code**

```
def remove(substring, string):
    sublen = len(substring)
    new_string = "" 

    for i in range(len(string)):
    
      if string[i:i+sublen] == substring:
          # found so append remaining string
          new_string += string[i+sublen:]
          break
      else:
          new_string += string[i]  # not found so append character

    return new_string 

print(remove("today", 'today is friday, the last friday of the month'))
```

**Output**

```
is friday, the last friday of the month
```

**Alternate Solution** (from your link)

```
def remove(substring, string)
    return string.replace(substring, '', 1)
```

This uses the `replace` function to replace the first occurrence of a string.

[Python String | replace](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-replace/) provides a good description of how this works.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a different approach: after you've found the indexes of the substring, create another string by concatenating two other pieces of the string without the substring:

```py
def remove(substring, string):
    sublen = len(substring)

    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i : i + sublen] == substring:
            return string[:i] + string[i + sublen:]
    return string


print(remove("wor", "Hello, world")) # Hello, ld
print(remove("an", "banana"))        # bana
print(remove("x", "banana"))         # banana
```

Answer (score 0):

DarrylG's `string.replace(substring, '', 1)` is better but you could also use `split` and `join`:

```
def remove1st(string,substring):
    return "".join(string.split(substring,1)) # 

remove1st("banana","na") # 'bana'
```

Comment: Why is `replace` better?

Comment: Because it performs the task in one (simple) operation as opposed to my split+join approach which requires two steps and allocation of a temporary list.  Neither of our solutions meet the "not to use a built-in method" requirement  tough.